# I am trying to move all of the objects at once, with no success

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a project that allows you to select a type of ninja and move around and attack enemies. I have the ninja selection done, but I am not sure how to move all of the objects that create the ninja. I've put multiple objects into a c.move function,  but I get this error:

```
c.move(self.hair,self.hair2,self.head,self.neck,self.chest,self.leg1,self.leg2,self.arm1,self.arm2,0,-5)
  File "C:\Users\mrden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2431, in move
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".2417470327664 move tagOrId xAmount yAmount
```

Here is my example code:

```
#Ninja Game
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
c=Canvas(width=800,height=600)
c.pack()
d = ""
class Ninja:
    def __init__(self,clan,):
        self.clan = clan
        if self.clan == "Uchiha":
         self.hair = c.create_polygon(52,485,52,452,99,452,99,485)
         self.head=c.create_rectangle(55,455,95,495,fill="white")
         self.hair2= c.create_polygon(74,452,83,477,99,452,fill="black")
        if self.clan == "Uzamaki":
         self.hair = c.create_polygon(52,485,52,452,99,452,99,485,fill="#FF3232")
         self.head=c.create_rectangle(55,455,95,495,fill="white")
        self.neck = c.create_rectangle(59,495,91,499)
        self.chest= c.create_rectangle(55,499,95,555)
        self.leg1 = c.create_rectangle(55,555,71,599)
        self.leg2 = c.create_rectangle(78,555,95,599)
        self.arm1=c.create_rectangle(42,499,55,555)
        self.arm2=c.create_rectangle(95,499,108,555)
    def move(self):
     if d == "U":
      if self.clan == "Uzamaki":
       c.move(self.hair,self.head,self.neck,self.chest,self.leg1,self.leg2,self.arm1,self.arm2,0,-5)
      if self.clan == "Uchiha":
       c.move(self.hair,self.hair2,self.head,self.neck,self.chest,self.leg1,self.leg2,self.arm1,self.arm2,0,-5)


n = Ninja("Uchiha")

def move_p(event):


    global d
    if event.keysym == "Up":
     d = "U"
     n.move()

c.bind_all("<KeyPress-Up>",move_p)
```

Answer (score 0):

The canvas allows you to add tags to items, so that you can treat whole groups of items as one. To do that, create a tag, add that tag to every item, and then use that tag when you move the item.

For example:

```
class Ninja:
    def __init__(self,clan,):
        self.clan = clan
        self.name = "ninja %d" % id(self)
        if self.clan == "Uchiha":
            self.hair = c.create_polygon(52,485,52,452,99,452,99,485, tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
            self.head=c.create_rectangle(55,455,95,495,fill="white", tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
            self.hair2= c.create_polygon(74,452,83,477,99,452,fill="black", tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
        if self.clan == "Uzamaki":
            self.hair = c.create_polygon(52,485,52,452,99,452,99,485,fill="#FF3232", tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
            self.head=c.create_rectangle(55,455,95,495,fill="white", tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
        self.neck = c.create_rectangle(59,495,91,499, tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
        self.chest= c.create_rectangle(55,499,95,555, tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
        self.leg1 = c.create_rectangle(55,555,71,599, tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
        self.leg2 = c.create_rectangle(78,555,95,599, tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
        self.arm1=c.create_rectangle(42,499,55,555, tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
        self.arm2=c.create_rectangle(95,499,108,555, tags=[self.name, "ninja"])

    def move(self):
        if d == "U":
            c.move(self.name, 0, -5)
```

If you also gave each ninja a common tag (eg: "ninja"), you could move all ninjas at once. The tags are a list, so you can give both a generic tag and one specific to this ninja.

For example:

```
c.create_polygon(..., tags=[self.name, "ninja"])
```

To move all ninjas at once

```
c.move("ninja", 0, -5)
```

To move a specific ninja:

```
c.move(n.name, 0, -5)
```

Comment: @Brian Oakley Thanks!